# Can signature verification expose a rootkit?

Tags: rootkit, digital-signature

I know that rootkits operate as part of the kernel, driver or service running on the system, injecting themself into DLLs or installing as a legitimate applications.

If I were to scan the system with `sigverif.exe`, would the files injected with the rootkit have broken signatures?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlikely. Most rootkits hide themselves so that any access with the standard Win32 APIs would display the original file (if it was patched) and ignore any extra files/services added by the rootkit.

Also, sigverif only verifies files it *knows to be signed* – any *additional* files would simply be ignored.

[RootkitRevealer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897445) is a more reliable tool. Some really nasty rootkits are only visible when comparing an online and offline scans (for example, from Windows itself and from a Linux CD).

Comment: How can you compare those 2? Is there a utility that does that?

Comment: @Dean: There *should* be, but I'm not aware of any :(